# Powershell to Remove IIS Logging Field

Tags: powershell, logging, iis

Trying to **remove** an existing IIS logging field for a specific site using PowerShell.

I have a PS that will add the desired fields, taken from [activate-iis-site-logging-field-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552280/activate-iis-site-logging-field-powershell) - this was the only method I could found to successfully add fields to a specific site *name*.

> ```
> Function Activate-LoggingField {
> param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$websiteName,
>       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$loggingField)
>
> $loggingFilter = "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name=`"$websiteName`"]/LogFile"
> $currentLoggingFields = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter $loggingFilter -Name LogExtFileFlags
> if ($currentLoggingFields -notmatch $loggingField)
> {
>     $newLoggingFields = "$currentLoggingFields,$loggingField"
>     Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter $loggingFilter -Name LogExtFileFlags -Value $newLoggingFields
> } }
> Activate-LoggingField -websiteName "SpecificSite" -loggingField
> > "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,SiteName,ComputerName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,BytesSent,BytesRecv,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Referer,ProtocolVersion,Host,HttpSubStatus"
> ```

If I use this command directly, I get an error - not sure why, as it should be the same command generated from above.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/Site[@name="SpecificSite"]/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags -Value "Date,Time" 
WARNING: Target configuration object 'System.Applicationhost/Sites/Site[@name=SpecificSite]/logfile is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'.
```

In my case, the **Cookie** field remains selected (periodically added by another application). No luck removing some or all the fields first, using Clear-WebConfiguration or Remove-WebConfiguration.

---

Side note: using the *id* instead of *name* works for specific sites (but is not scalable across servers). From applicationHost.config:

```
<site name="SpecificSite" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
```

So I'd think I could use [@name=SpecificSite] in a command all by itself, but using the site name doesn't seem to work unless the name is a variable. Expected?

this works

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.applicationHost/sites/site[@id=2]/LogFile -Name LogExtFileFlags
```

but this does not (with or without quotes around the name, not using a variable for the name)

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name=SpecificSite]/LogFile -Name LogExtFileFlags
```

> //post-accepted edit - my mistake was not wrapping the entire -Filter value in quotes. I was just using quotes on around "SpecificSite". I used the site ID first, which works without any quotes - that threw me off. Thanks again.

Comment: Your ```$loggingFilter``` has quotes in the actual string value because they're escaped with a backtick, whereas your second ```Get-WebConfigurationProperty``` example doesn't have any quotes around the ```SpecificSite```. Try doing your ```Get-``` / ```Set-WebConfigurationProperty``` as a 2-liner  ```$loggingFilter = "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name=`"$websiteName`"]/LogFile"``` and then ```Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter $loggingFilter -Name LogExtFileFlags``` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two powershell commands to add fields and remove all fields with correct format. You can refer to it.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='sitename']/logFile" -name "logExtFileFlags" -value "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,SiteName,ComputerName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,BytesSent,BytesRecv,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Cookie,Referer,ProtocolVersion,Host,HttpSubStatus"


Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='sitename']/logFile" -name "logExtFileFlags" -value ""
```